# Inserting into postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I am working trying to write an insert query into a backup database.  I writing place and entities tables into this database.  The issue is entities is linked to place via place.id column.  I added a column place.original_id in the place table to store it's original 'id'. so now that i entered place into the new database it's id column changed but i have the original id stored so I can still link entities table to it.  I am trying to figure out how to write entities to get the new id

so far i am at this point:

```
insert into entities_backup (id, place_id)
select 
  nextval('public.entities_backup_id_seq'),
  (select id from places where original_id = (select place_id from entities) as place_id
 from
   entities
```

I know I am missing something because this does not work.  I need to grab the id column from places when entity.place_id = places.original_id.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you considered using [Postgres's built in backup and restore mechanisms](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup.html)? And is that semicolon supposed to be in there?

Comment: no its suppose to be a comma.  I am actually copying these tables to this postgres database and storing.  Its a onetime project.  The original data is in a oracle table, i just need to bring it to postgres so I can use it with another project with out messing up the original data.  That is why the ID columns do not match perfectly.

Comment: How did you do the Oracle dump? Did both `places` and `entities` come over from Oracle?

Comment: yes, i dropped them to a csv file and then imported the csv files into temp tables in postgres.  Then taking the csv dumps into the active tables in postgres.

Comment: Why did you not retain the original IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
insert into entities_backup (id, place_id)
select nextval('public.entities_backup_id_seq'), places.id 
from places, entities
where places.original_id = entities.place_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I am working trying to write an insert query into a backup database. I writing place and entities tables into this database. The issue is entities is linked to place via place.id column. I added a column place.original_id in the place table to store it's original 'id'. so now that i entered place into the new database it's id column changed but i have the original id stored so I can still link entities table to it.*

It would be simpler to not have this problem in the first place.

Rather than trying to fix this up after the fact, the better solution is to dump and load `places` and `entities` complete with their primary and foreign keys intact. Oracle's [EXPORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm) or a utility such as [ora2pg](http://ora2pg.darold.net/) should be able to do it.

Sorry I can't say more. I know Postgres, not Oracle.